# Django Rest Response when data is already in JSON

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
class Ebay(APIView):
    #permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    #renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer,)
    def get(self):
        search = EbayFind(keywords='phone')
        result = search.get_results()
        return Response(result.json())
        #return HttpResponse(result.json()) this returns it correctly
```

I have created a simple non-model API endpoint using DRF to return some JSON using `results.json()` on a requests object. It is again converted into JSON in the Response (giving double backslashes and ruining the JSON), whereas `HttpResponse` returns it fine. I haven't set any default renderer in settings.py so how could I stop it converting the response to JSON for this endpoint?

Comment: so why not returning `Response(result)`?

Comment: Does `results.json()` return a string or dictionary-like object?

Comment: it returns a dict.